# Is there a javafx panel the user can resize?

Tags: javafx, panel, resizable

I need a javafx component that has a right and left panel with a draggable bar in between so the user can resize the 2 panels. Im having a bunch of trouble finding this - it has to exist. Not sure what it would be called so not sure what to search for. It would be a border container but one you can drag the separators to resize.

There is something like it demoed here:
http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/themePreviewer/demo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [SplitPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html).